# Display a limited number of items in the filtered array with a load more button

Tags: reactjs

I have this component **Cat** that pulls the data from a local json file and displays all the Cats from the file in the alphabetical order. I need to display first **10 cats**, and then have a **Load More** button to display the rest. Does anyone have a solution on how to do it in a good way? The line   {providerNumber.length} Cats still needs to show the total number of cats, not the first 10.

Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Error from './Error.jsx';



export default class Cat extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      providersData: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), 500);
    fetch('../feed/sample.json')
    .then(response => { console.log(response); return response.json()})
    .then(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData)



      this.setState({ providersData: [...responseData.providers].sort((a,b) => {
        const aName = a.companyName.toUpperCase()
        const bName = b.companyName.toUpperCase()
        if (aName < bName) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (aName > bName) {
          return 1
        }
          // names must be equal
          return 0
        })
      });

    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
    });
  }


  render() {
      const { loading } = this.state;
      const providerNumber = this.state.providersData.filter(provider => provider.yearStarted >= 2010 && provider.type === 'cat')

      if(loading) {
        return (
          <div>  <img src="./../assets/loader.svg" alt=""/></div>
        ); // render loading when app is not ready
      }
      return this.state.providersData.length ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Cats</h1>
          <div> {providerNumber.length} Cats</div>
          {this.state.providersData.map(function(provider, index) {
            if (provider.yearStarted >= 2010 && provider.type === 'cat') {
              return (
                <div key={index} className="job">
                  <h2>{provider.companyName}</h2>
                  <img src={provider.images['Company Logo'].url} alt=""/>
                </div>
              )
            }
          })}
        </div>
      ) : <Error />
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this before you call `.map` in your render:

```
this.state.providersData.slice(0, this.state.numberOfCatsShown).map(...)
```

You would need to initialize `this.state.numberOfCatsShown` to 10 in your constructor first.

When you want to display more cats, use a function that looks like this:

```
showMoreCats() {
  const newNumberOfCatsShown = this.state.numberOfCatsShown + 10;
  // set it to the length of the array to show all the cats.
  this.setState({ numberOfCatsShown: newNumberOfCatsShown });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! what happens here is that it displays only 3 items instead of 10. I think it's because we are slicing it before mapping, so it displays first 10 items out of 100 total. Then out of those 10, it maps 3 that match "cat" and displays those. How do I slice the actual mapped results?

Comment: You can try filtering before the slice instead of doing it inside the map. You can do something like `data.filter((provider) => provider.yearStarted >= 2010 && provider.type === 'cat').slice(...).map(...)` and take out the if statement from you map callback.

Comment: Thank you! last question - when I create the Show More button I created this function inside render()  like you described. -   function handleClick () {
  
        const numberShown = this.state.numberShown + 10;
        // set it to the length of the array to show all the cats.
        this.setState({ numberShown: newNumberShown });
      } , but it says that it can't access state within the function. any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: this is the button - <button onClick={handleClick}>Show More</button>

Comment: It should be an instance method. You will also need to bind it in your constructor.

Comment: Would you mind giving more detail on this? I tried to do an instance but I might be doing it wrong as nothing is working :/

Comment: Just solved it - added   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); to constuctor and it worked. Thank you!